# How can I make a draggable/adjustable ROI in OpenCV/Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, user-controls

Prior to performing my processing algorithm on an image, I need the user to click-draw a circle to create a clipping mask using the mouse.  This mask will be used to remove areas of the image that will cause my algorithm to fail.

How can I allow the user to:

1. drag the ROI (to adjust x-y position on the image)
2. adjust the shape of the ROI (i.e. the size of the circle by dragging)

In the future I will need to use some feature detection to make the ROI choice, but for now I really need the user to be able to define the ROI in a way that is easy for them,

Answer (score 3):

If you have `scikit-image` installed, you can use the following to do a rectangular selection (modifying the skimage code to do a circle instead would not be hard, though):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.viewer.canvastools import RectangleTool

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data.camera(), interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')

props = {'facecolor': '#000070',
         'edgecolor': 'white',
         'alpha': 0.3}
rect_tool = RectangleTool(ax, rect_props=props)

plt.show()
print("Final selection:")
rect_tool.callback_on_enter(rect_tool.extents)
```

You press enter to finalize the selection.

[image: Rectangle Selector]

Comment: For Mac OSX users:  I had to change the backend -- adding:

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

just *before*

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

in order to get rid of AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region'

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've filed an issue: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/884

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ax'` on the line `rect_tool = RectangleTool(ax, rect_props=props)`. `System Info: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS; Anaconda Environment; Python3.8`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `skimage.viewer` is also deprecated now; perhaps take a look at Napari.

Answer (score 3):

The piece of code given by Stefan must not be supported anymore (it fails when ax is passed to RectangleTool). RectangleTool only takes skimage viewer as argument. Here is a piece of code adapted from Stephan example and [skimage documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.viewer.canvastools.html#skimage.viewer.canvastools.RectangleTool). It provides an interactive way for retrieving ROI coordinates.

```
from pylab import *
from skimage import data
from skimage.viewer.canvastools import RectangleTool
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer

im = data.camera()

def get_rect_coord(extents):
    global viewer,coord_list
    coord_list.append(extents)

def get_ROI(im):
    global viewer,coord_list

    selecting=True
    while selecting:
        viewer = ImageViewer(im)
        coord_list = []
        rect_tool = RectangleTool(viewer, on_enter=get_rect_coord) 
        print "Draw your selections, press ENTER to validate one and close the window when you are finished"
        viewer.show()
        finished=raw_input('Is the selection correct? [y]/n: ')
        if finished!='n':
            selecting=False
    return coord_list

a=get_ROI(im)
print a
```